# Added columns to datasource not visible in Power Query (Excel)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using a folder with .csv files as a source for my data in power query. Now I added some columns to this source files, but when I refresh my connection these extra columns are not loaded in excel. Any idea how I can add these columns?

```
Source = Folder.Files("\\pathtocsv"),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File from Sources", each #"Transform File from Sources"([Content])),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File from Sources"}),
#"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File from Sources", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from Sources"(#"Sample File"))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In auto-generated Helper Queries change Columns parameter in Transform File function. New columns should then be visible down the line.

[image]